# Trouble renaming key in array of documents

Tags: mongodb

I have an array of documents as such:

```
"players" : [
    {
        "approved" : true,
        "isGM" : true,
        "user" : {
            "userID" : 1,
            "username" : "User 1"
        }
    }
],
```

I'm trying to rename `userID` to `userId` with

```
db.games.update({}, { $rename: { 'players.user.userID': 'players.user.userId' } });
```

But when I do, I get `cannot use the part (players of players.user.userID) to traverse the element`. How can I rename these fields and why the current method doesn't work?

Comment: `"players"` is an array. At present you need to match each element of the array individually and issue the rename. Just the same as any update, all the techniques are outlined on the linked duplicate.

Comment: I apologize for the dup. I did search before asking, but didn't find an answer I thought matched. I can see where my logic was wrong. Sorry.